# How to assign c# guid value to javascript variable using razor viewmodel in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view model with property of `Guid` type. I need to assign it to javascript object property and post this object to some action method.

When I write (in javascript):

```
var partyId = @Model.Id;  // "Id" is of Guid type
```

I get

```
var partyId = 6abbf77d-ba28-4d8a-87ff-2fa8f8a070c9;
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

How can I handle this? I mean assign `Id` value to javascript variable.

Comment: What happens if you enclose @Model.Id within single quotes?

Comment: post Your answer and I will accept it, cause You were first

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enclose @Model.Id within quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Your JavaScript output is ultimately going to be a string, so it will formatted as such using quotes:

```
var partyId = '6abbf77d-ba28-4d8a-87ff-2fa8f8a070c9';
```

Your current snippet is missing this and is just rendering the raw value.

I'm unaware of any GUID *type* in JavaScript to parse it between, though, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can enclose the model with single or double quotes.  You may receive weird parsing errors doing that, but you can typically get rid of them by enclosing the vb/c# code with parentheses.

```
var partyId = '@(Model.Id)';
```

Answer (score 2):

Enclose it in quotes?

```
var partyId = '@Model.Id';
```